# Tests fail when throw exception anywhere in TEST macro googletest

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

I have some problems with google testing framework

So, when I run the following code:

```
void f(){
    throw runtime_error("");
}

TEST(test, test1){
    EXPECT_THROW(f(), std::runtime_error);
}
```

So, I got such error:

```
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/gTest.dir/build.make:101: test/gTest] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'test/gTest'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:173: test/CMakeFiles/gTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

But when f() does not throw anything, so test just not passed. Even if I use try catch it still shows me the same error

Could you help to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Google test must show the call stack. Please post it

Comment: @S.M. but it does not. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with type of exception, thanks. Presented code works